# Build a QT program from command line

Tags: qt, jenkins, cmd, makefile, path

I know this question has already been asked, but I encounter an issue that I haven't seen elsewhere.

I am trying to build automatically a QT program on Jenkins through a JenkinsFile.
So I want to build this program in command line.

On Qt Creator, everything works fine, my makefile is generated and the program compiles.

But when I manually type the exact commands that are executed in Qt on a terminal (cmd and cygwin), the compilation fails. 
The errors are usually `ld: cannot find -lXXXXXX`

My guess is that it is an environment problem so I tried to add some lib paths in the `$PATH`, `$LIBRARY_PATH`, and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables but it doesn't resolve the problem. The error just becomes `Undefined reference to ___XXXXXX`

I would appreciate some help on this issue !

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The building (slave) machine is a windows 7. Here is a screenshot of the compilation stage in Qt (which works fine). The commands I try to type in a terminal are exactly the same as the blue lines on the screenshot. (sorry some lines are written in French)

[image: Building steps]

Comment: On the Jenkins system, do you have installed the development packages for all required libraries? And the correct versions of them? Are they installed in the standard system location (like e.g. `/usr/lib/` or similar) or in a custom location? For custom locations, have you added flags to your build system to find the libraries?

Comment: Actually, no I didn't check if all that was well configured on Jenkins. 

But my problem is not specific to Jenkins. Maybe I was not really clear in my first post ...

My Jenkins job failed several times so I decided to compile my program directly on the slave machine in a terminal (not using Jenkins). This is where I encounter this issue. So I don't think that it is related to Jenkins configuration (maybe I will have to check it later but right now I just want to compile my program on my building machine) !

Hope this is more clear

Comment: When I said "Jenkins system" I meant "the *machine* where you run Jenkins", I didn't intend to imply the use of Jenkins itself. Anyway, the questions in my previous comment still stand, as once you can build properly from the command-line, you should also be able to use an automated system (like Jenkins) to build.

Comment: Oh ok my bad I misunderstood ... To answer your questions I guess that the correct versions of the required libraries are installed because there is no compilation problem on Qt. I guess that if they weren't there it would fail on Qt too, no ? 
And what do you mean by "adding flags" ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From the error message `ld: cannot find -lXXXXXX` and the environment variables, I would suppose that you are compiling in Linux/Unix. Now, if you are compiling with g++, the environment variables `$PATH`, `$LIBRARY_PATH`, and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't have any effect on finding libraries. What you may try is an -L argument to the compiler telling it where the library is located, I mean:

```
g++ -L /path/to/libXXXXX.so -l XXXXX -o result source.cpp
```

Comment: No actually, the machine is a Windows 7 (I edited my first post with some explanations). However I tried to use cygwin as terminal which uses linux commands

Comment: Then your compiler is mingw. This is important to know, because you are asking for the command line syntax. Anyway, the "-L" argument is also applicable, but the library should be a DLL file instead of so. [Here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW) is some documentation about library locations with mingw.